# How to verify avalanche block is accepted with web3.py

Tags: python, blockchain, cryptocurrency, web3py, avalanche

I am trying to build a bot that listens to events on AMMs for various chains and I am running into issues when trying to build out my algorithm for the avalanche network. When calling the `getLogs` function for a particular event, the program will randomly crash with the following error

```
ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'requested to block ... after last accepted block ...'}
```

My program is only ever retrieves logs up to the `latest` block so I am not sure why this error is occurring (I assume it has something to do with the way avax nodes reach consensus).

How can I verify if a block is accepted prior to running `getLogs`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get ABI of the smart contract and also its address in order to run it.

```
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=ContractAddress, abi=abi)
my_filter = contract.events.<YOUR_EVENT>.createFilter(fromBlock='latest')
entries = my_filter.get_all_entries()
```